# How to display information from a Python list in "Age: 18" format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is some example data:

```
EXAMPLE_DATA = [
['time', 'age', 'height', 'width', 'ethnicity', 'religion'],
['18:42:11', '61', '153.9615', '0.8', 'Mixed', 'None']
['18:35:00', '34', '116.4253333', '10.17', 'Mixed', 'None']
```

I want to display this data in the format:

```
Time: 18:42:11
Age: 61
Height: 153.9615
```

If possible, you can see that in my example data there are two data entries, so if I could I would like to print it like this:

```
DATA 1
Time: 18:42:11
Age: 61
Height: 153.9615
Width: 0.8
Ethnicity: Mixed
Religion: None

DATA 2
Time: 18:35:00
Age: 34
Height: 116.4253333
Width: 10.17
Ethnicity: Mixed
Religion: None
```

Sorry if the question isn't specific enough, I can give any other specific information if needed. Thanks.

Comment: You should use a dictionary in first place.

Comment: @Austin Is that something to do with Dictreader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
EXAMPLE_DATA = [
    ['time', 'age', 'height', 'width', 'ethnicity', 'religion'],
    ['18:42:11', '61', '153.9615', '0.8', 'Mixed', 'None'],
    ['18:35:00', '34', '116.4253333', '10.17', 'Mixed', 'None']]

headers, *rows = EXAMPLE_DATA

for i, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    print("DATA{}".format(i))
    for header, column in zip(headers, row):
        print('{}: {}'.format(header, column))
    print()
```

**Output**

```
DATA1
time: 18:42:11
age: 61
height: 153.9615
width: 0.8
ethnicity: Mixed
religion: None

DATA2
time: 18:35:00
age: 34
height: 116.4253333
width: 10.17
ethnicity: Mixed
religion: None
```

**UPDATE**

```
EXAMPLE_DATA = [
    ['time', 'age', 'height', 'width', 'ethnicity', 'religion'],
    ['18:42:11', '61', '153.9615', '0.8', 'Mixed', 'None'],
    ['18:35:00', '34', '116.4253333', '10.17', 'Mixed', 'None']]

headers, *rows = EXAMPLE_DATA

for i, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    print("DATA{}".format(i))
    for header, column in zip(headers, row):
        if header in ('time', 'age', 'height'):
            print('{}: {}'.format(header, column))
    print()
```

**Output**

```
DATA1
time: 18:42:11
age: 61
height: 153.9615

DATA2
time: 18:35:00
age: 34
height: 116.4253333
```

Comment: That is perfect thank you! Is there a way to put a new line before 'DATA 2'?

Comment: @Largo Updated the answer!

Comment: Sorry for asking another question, but say for example I only wanted to print the data for time, age and height how would I do this? Thanks